# Getting illegal request to write non-integral number of frames exception ONLY when running with jar

Tags: java, audio, intellij-idea

I'm getting an exception ONLY when the program is run with a jar file. When I run it through IntelliJ i don't get the exception. Here's my code:

opening the SourceDataLine (`clip` is an InputStream):

```
    Frmt = new AudioFormat(44100, 16, 2, true, false);
    Info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, Frmt);
    Bfr = new byte[409600];
    NBToRead = 409600;
    try
    {
        LineIn = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(Info);
        LineIn.open(Frmt);
        TotalToRead = Clip.available();
    }
    catch (LineUnavailableException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

playing the audio:

```
    LineIn.start();
    try
    {
        while (Total < TotalToRead && !Stopped)
        {
                NBRead = Clip.read(Bfr, 0, NBToRead);
                if (NBRead == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                Total += NBRead;
                LineIn.write(Bfr, 0, NBRead);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LineIn.stop();
```

I'm getting an `IllegalArgumentException` on this line:

```
                LineIn.write(Bfr, 0, NBRead);
```

Comment: Not sure if it's related to your problem but the second parameter to `Clip.read` should probably be `Total`. Otherwise, you are just continually reading from the beginning of the file.

Comment: @jaket when I do that, I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: What exception are you getting? What line? Can you post an example so that others can easily reproduce your problem?

Comment: @user3697209 you should probably also decrement NBToRead by NBRead